# linux network, iptables, nat как настроить проброс при FORWARD DROP?

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, nat, forward

есть определенная топология сети(на картинке)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не получается настроить правила для iptables, что бы можно было подключиться по telnet от ws22 к r1 (и наоборот, об этом дальше)
есть скрипт firewall.sh
в нем изначально следующие правила:
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -X

iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT

---

1. Включить SNAT, а именно маскирование всех локальных ip из локальной сети, находящейся за r2
2. Включить DNAT на 8080 порт машины r2 и добавить к веб-серверу Apache, запущенному на ws22, доступ извне сети
3. Проверить соединение по telnet

---

Не получается подключиться по telnet, если убрать FORWARD DROP, то работает, из чего делаю вывод, что не правильно прописываю какие то разрешения для протоколов
Мой код:
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -X

iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.20.0.0/26 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.0.12

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.0.20:80

(еще пробовал добавить такое:
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
)

---

Не работает не понимаю, что делаю не так, и поидее по заданию еще сказано что это сделать как то в два правила, то есть правило snat и dnat

А и еще на ws22 и r1 запущен apache и слушает 0.0.0.0:80, то есть общедоступный

Как нужно правильно прописать правила в iptables ?